# How to extract and change a sequence of bytes from a serial packet to the correct integer representation in python?

Tags: python, int, hex, pyserial

`374c4f4f00000800ff74**d102**29190300006f00fffffffffffffffffffff`

This is the serial packet I am processing using pyserial. The two bytes in bold actually correspond to a real world measurement which corresponds to `721`(decimal) or `02d1`(hex). How do I extract those bytes in python and get the correct int value which is 721?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Processing to and from such byte strings is quickly and easily done with the `struct` library functions `pack`/`pack_to`  and `unpack`/`unpack_from`:

While it is normally best practice to unpack/unpack the entire packet you can use the _from & _to versions to selectively manipulate packets.

In your case:

```
>>> import struct
>>> val # Generated using  binascii.unhexlify
 b'7LOO\x00\x00\x08\x00\xfft\xd1\x02)\x19\x03\x00\x00o\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> struct.unpack_from('<H', val, 10)
(721,) # Note the return is a tupple so you need the 0th element
>>> struct.unpack_from('<H', val, 10)[0]
721
```

### More info

```
>>> import struct
>>> help (struct.unpack)
Help on built-in function unpack in module _struct:

unpack(...)
    unpack(fmt, buffer) -> (v1, v2, ...)

    Return a tuple containing values unpacked according to the format string
    fmt.  Requires len(buffer) == calcsize(fmt). See help(struct) for more
    on format strings.
>>> help (struct.pack)
Help on built-in function pack in module _struct:

pack(...)
    pack(fmt, v1, v2, ...) -> bytes

    Return a bytes object containing the values v1, v2, ... packed according
    to the format string fmt.  See help(struct) for more on format strings.

>>> help(struct)
Help on module struct:

NAME
    struct

DESCRIPTION
    Functions to convert between Python values and C structs.
    Python bytes objects are used to hold the data representing the C struct
    and also as format strings (explained below) to describe the layout of data
    in the C struct.

    The optional first format char indicates byte order, size and alignment:
      @: native order, size & alignment (default)
      =: native order, std. size & alignment
      <: little-endian, std. size & alignment
      >: big-endian, std. size & alignment
      !: same as >

    The remaining chars indicate types of args and must match exactly;
    these can be preceded by a decimal repeat count:
      x: pad byte (no data); c:char; b:signed byte; B:unsigned byte;
      ?: _Bool (requires C99; if not available, char is used instead)
      h:short; H:unsigned short; i:int; I:unsigned int;
      l:long; L:unsigned long; f:float; d:double.
    Special cases (preceding decimal count indicates length):
      s:string (array of char); p: pascal string (with count byte).
    Special cases (only available in native format):
      n:ssize_t; N:size_t;
      P:an integer type that is wide enough to hold a pointer.
    Special case (not in native mode unless 'long long' in platform C):
      q:long long; Q:unsigned long long
    Whitespace between formats is ignored.

    The variable struct.error is an exception raised on errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hex-encoded string is of odd length, so I don't know where the padding's missing from, see below

```
In [18]: s = '374c4f4f00000800ff74d10229190300006f00fffffffffffffffffffff0' # a nibble of padding at the end

In [19]: buffer = binascii.unhexlify(s)

In [20]: buffer
Out[20]: b'7LOO\x00\x00\x08\x00\xfft\xd1\x02)\x19\x03\x00\x00o\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xf0'

In [21]: struct.unpack('<10BH18B', buffer)
Out[21]:
(55,
 76,
 79,
 79,
 0,
 0,
 8,
 0,
 255,
 116,
 721,
 ...
```

For more information on what the format strings in `pack` and `unpack` can be, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html?highlight=pack#struct-format-strings). In short, `<` stands for little-endian, `B` for unsigned char (assumed 8-bit width), `H` for short (assumed 16-bit width).

Answer (score 0):

Since the actual format strings are somewhat strange at first sight, I have given you a solution based on the above answer:

- The command unhexlify will convert the 4 byte ascii representation back to a two byte binary representation of your integer.
- the '<' takes care of your reversed byte order in your integer [(Formatting details)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)
- The 'i' means that we are facing a two byte integer

Hope that helps.

```
import struct 
from binascii import unhexlify

s ="374c4f4f00000800ff74d10229190300006f00fffffffffffffffffffff"
s1= s[20:24]

print struct.unpack('<h', unhexlify(s1))[0]
```